# Add a panel to a fxml pane

Tags: java, javafx, panel, fxml

I am new to JavaFX and I am trying to do an app that will show several panels from the same class: The class PacienteGUI creates a panel, and I want to show 5 of this PacienteGUI panels in my main FXML, which has a panel itself.    I´ve tried to add it through the controller by

```
@FXML Pane principal;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    PacienteGUI paciente = new PacienteGUI(1);
    principal.getChildren().add(paciente);
}
```

Part of the PacienteGUI:

```
public class PacienteGUI extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public PacienteGUI(int num) {
    chairNum = num;
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
..
..
..Creates JPanel with all its components
..
}
```

The problem is that it says that PacientesGUI cannot be converted to node. How can I solve this??

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the `PacienteGUI` class?

Comment: I edited to show part of it, although the initComponents() is way too long to post. Just basic Swing components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Paciente` class is a Swing `JPanel`, which cannot be placed in a JavaFX `Pane` directly.

You either need to make `Paciente` a subclass of a JavaFX `Pane`, or you need to wrap the `Paciente` instance in a [`SwingNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html). The latter (`SwingNode`) is tricky, because you will need to use two different threads to create the different components: swing components need to be created and accessed on the AWT event dispatching thread, and JavaFX components need to be created on the FX Application Thread. I strongly recommend **not** mixing JavaFX and Swing if you can do so.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do this because I couldnt figure out hou to add a PacienteGUI.fxml I already had into the main FXML. So I will make a JavaFX PacienteGUI, or how can I add the FXML to the main FXML??

Comment: You can include one FXML inside another with a [`<fx:include>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements) element. Alternatively, you can load the content with an `FXMLLoader` and add it to the `principal` panel you defined.